# What parameters does the stringlength attribute errormessage take?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

In the MVC4 template one of the data annotation attributes used is stringlength.

For example:

```
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
```

What parameters {0}, {1}, {2} (more?) are legal?

Edit: To be more specific, I can see from the example and trial and error what the possibilities are, but I would like to see some hard documentation.

I can't find anything about this in the [StringLengthAttribute documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679251.aspx).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The `{0}` index is the display name of property, `{1}` is the `MaximumLength`, `{2}` is the `MinimumLength`. So, your error message will be formate as `"The Foo must be at least 6 characters long."`

Comment: Yes, well I guess what I am really asking is, how can I know this, apart from trial and error. Is it implemented in the StringLengthAttribute class itself in the [FormatErrorMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.formaterrormessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method? Is this documented?

Comment: What if `MinimumLength` wasn't specified? And if what if it's the only property that was set while `MaximumLength` is zero?

Comment: No idea if it was true many years ago when this was answered, but the docs currently state this in remarks.    
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute?view=netcore-3.1#remarks

Answer (score 12):

I haven't seen any documentation either, but the `FormatErrorMessage` method for the `StringLengthAttribute` looks like this:

```
public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
{
    EnsureLegalLengths();
    string format = ((this.MinimumLength != 0) && !base.CustomErrorMessageSet) ? DataAnnotationsResources.StringLengthAttribute_ValidationErrorIncludingMinimum : base.ErrorMessageString;
    return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, format, new object[] { name, MaximumLength, MinimumLength });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A longer-than-expected Google search brought me to this old topic before I could start getting some solid leads, so I'll put this here and hope it helps anyone else in the same shoes:

Inspecting the code for [StringLengthAttribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/StringLengthAttribute.cs) that MS put up on GitHub confirms the logic residing in the FormatErrorMessage method:

```
// it's ok to pass in the minLength even for the error message without a {2} param since String.Format will just
// ignore extra arguments
return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, errorMessage, name, this.MaximumLength, this.MinimumLength);
```

Thus '0', '1', and '2' corresponds to 'name' (of Property), 'MaximumLength', and 'MinimumLength' accordingly.

I bet the same method can be applied to all other validation attributes to check their formatting parameters accordingly; I was not able to find any other documentation for this infomation otherwise.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The current one does not explain where the information is coming from.