# Substituting string in C# attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, asp.net-mvc-5

When create new MVC5 application, there is a ViewModel with this property:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "New password")]
public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```

I'm interesting in this part:

```
ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long."
```

I believe that `{0}` gets string from `[Display(Name = "New password")]` and `{2}` gets string from `MinimumLength = 6`.

What I don't understand, is why they are in this particular order? I mean why exactly `{2}` and not, say, `{1}` gets value from `MinimumLength = 6`? The same question for `{0}`. How can I determine this order?

Is next declaration would be correct? I expect that `{0}` gets display name and `{1}` - `length: 25`.

```
[MinLength(length: 25, ErrorMessage = "Length of {0} must be at least {1} characters long.")]
[Display(Name = "My property")]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

What would be if I remove attribute `[Display(Name = "My property")]`? Does `{0}` in that case just takes name of my property `"MyProperty"`?

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425320/what-parameters-does-the-stringlength-attribute-errormessage-take - the `{1}` is for `MaximumLength`, but it simply seems badly documented

Comment: Thanks, that explains behaviour of `StringLengthAttribute`, but what about other attributes? Does `{0}` always refers to display name? And can I use `[MinLength(length: 25, ErrorMessage = "Length of {0} must be at least {1} characters long.")]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***"What is why they are in this particular order?"***

The order is:

1. **`Display Name`**
2. **`MaximumLength`**
3. **`MinimumLength`**

The answer on question string frormat is in **`FormatErrorMessage`** method of **`StringLengthAttribute.cs`**:

```
public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name) {
    this.EnsureLegalLengths();

    bool useErrorMessageWithMinimum = this.MinimumLength != 0 && !this.CustomErrorMessageSet;

    string errorMessage = useErrorMessageWithMinimum ?
        DataAnnotationsResources.StringLengthAttribute_ValidationErrorIncludingMinimum : this.ErrorMessageString;

    // it's ok to pass in the minLength even for the error message without a {2} param since String.Format will just
    // ignore extra arguments
    return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, errorMessage, name, this.MaximumLength, this.MinimumLength);
}
```

---

***"What would be if I remove attribute [Display(Name = "My property")]? Does {0} in that case just takes name of my property "MyProperty"***:

**Yes it would use member name.**

Here is a code of DisplayName property which is passed as **`name`** to **`FormatErrorMessage`**:

```
public string DisplayName {
    get {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._displayName)) {
            this._displayName = this.GetDisplayName();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._displayName)) {
                this._displayName = this.MemberName;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._displayName)) {
                    this._displayName = this.ObjectType.Name;
                }
            }
        }
        return this._displayName;
    }   
}
```