# The {0} must be at least {2} characters long

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013

I have a Visual Studio 2013 MVC Razor project that I am studying by walking through one of the examples on [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/).

In the chapter on [ASP.NET MVC Security](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_security.asp), you will see the default file `AccountModels.cs` in the Models class with the following text for each of the **Password** fields:

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```

I am familiar with String.Format, where the parameters must start from 0 and increment up.

The 2nd parameter above, however, jumps to 2, and it does not appear to have enough parameters being passed to the string.

When learning a project, I do what I can to customize features (like string responses) to better enforce my learning.

### What is going on here?

[image: pictures rock]

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/StringLengthAttribute.cs,76

Comment: w3schools isn't the best resource for accurate information. They've cleaned up much of the html and javascript tutorials, but I'm not sure about ASP.NET. I would recommend sticking with http://www.asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: StringLengthAttribute class constructor]

We are basically calling a constructor of a class:

The `StringLengthAttribute` is a class, and its constructor has one `int` parameter called `maximumLength`

It also has some `Properties`:

- `ErrorMessage` of type `string`

  - in our case it's the string: `"The {0} must be at least {2} characters long."`
- `ErrorMessageResourceName` of type `string`

  - in our case we don't give it any value
- `ErrorMessageResourceType` of type `System.Type`

  - in our case we don't give it any value
- `MinimumLength` of type `int`

  - in our case we give it the value `6`

the `ErrorMessageResourceName` string has nothing to do (yet) with the other properties, so it is nothing like this:

<strike>`String.Format("some variable {0} and some other {1}...", 100, 6)`</strike>

so the number `100` and the property `MinimumLength = 6` are **not at all** (yet) parameters sent to be formatted with the string `"The {0} must be at least {2} characters long."`.

The class `StringLengthAttribute` also has some methods, one of them is called `FormatErrorMessage`

This method is called internally to format the message, and it internally formats the string using `String.Format`, and here is when the parameters are passed to the string to be correctly formatted.

- {0} is bound to DisplayName
- {1} is bound to MaximumLength
- {2} is bound to MinimumLength

this is the method that is called internally (if you want to know how it internally does it):

```
/// <summary>
    /// Override of <see cref="ValidationAttribute.FormatErrorMessage"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name to include in the formatted string</param>
    /// <returns>A localized string to describe the maximum acceptable length</returns>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"> is thrown if the current attribute is ill-formed.</exception>
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name) {
        this.EnsureLegalLengths();

        bool useErrorMessageWithMinimum = this.MinimumLength != 0 && !this.CustomErrorMessageSet;

        string errorMessage = useErrorMessageWithMinimum ?
            DataAnnotationsResources.StringLengthAttribute_ValidationErrorIncludingMinimum : this.ErrorMessageString;

        // it's ok to pass in the minLength even for the error message without a {2} param since String.Format will just
        // ignore extra arguments
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, errorMessage, name, this.MaximumLength, this.MinimumLength);
    }
```

References:

- Microsoft Reference Source [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/StringLengthAttribute.cs)
- A similar question on Stackoverflow: "What parameters does the stringlength attribute errormessage take?" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425320/what-parameters-does-the-stringlength-attribute-errormessage-take)
- The almost useless msdn documentation for `StringLengthAttribute Class` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Your answer says about the same thing as mine, but answer awarded because it is much more detailed. Thanks, Mr. Castano.

Answer (score 3):

After a little more investigating, I found an answer posted on the [ASP.NET Forum by CodeHobo](http://forums.asp.net/t/1696931.aspx?Usage%20of%20StringLengthAttribute%20ErrorMessage):

> You can find the full documentation here
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.aspx
>
> [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The password must be at least {0} characters", MinimumLength = 6)]
>
> In this case error message is just a string template that is applied when rendered. Think of a string.Format. So it is equivalent to
>
> string.Format("The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.",DisplayName,MaximumLength,MinimumLength);
>
> The 0 index is the display name of the property, 1 is the maximum length, 2 is the minimum length
>
> For your example, this would show the display name instead of the minimum length. You need to change {0} to {2}
>
> [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The password must be at least {0} characters", MinimumLength = 6)]

Yes, I could have simply deleted my question, but SO is my primary source of programming information.

If I don't find a programming answer here, I feel it needs it.

I don't quite yet understand the answer 100%, so if anyone has a better answer, I would gladly accept it.

Comment: This was somewhat discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540314/modify-default-errormessage-for-stringlength-validation, but you're correct in that the structure of the format string is not really covered in the MSDN.

Comment: This confused me also. Thank you very much for answering your own question and not deleting it. I found your question and answer by doing a Google search.