# Override max length error message in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to override the max length error message in ASP.net MVC. Basically, I would like to make the error message string as follow:

[DisplayName] length should not be more than [x]. However, I do not know how to include the displayname attribute value inside.

```
public class MyMaxLengthAttribute : MaxLengthAttribute
{
    public MyMaxLengthAttribute(int length) : base(length)
    {
        ErrorMessage = "What should I input here"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the `StringLengthAttribute` `{0}` refers to the display name and `{2}` refers to the length.

```
public class MyMaxLengthAttribute : StringLengthAttribute
{
    public MyMaxLengthAttribute(int length) : base(length)
    {
        ErrorMessage = "{0} length should not be more than {2}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup. this is probably what I want. May i know where to get reference on what {0}, {1}, {2} refers for each and every attribute. besides, is it possible to straight away override the stringlength attribute without inheriting?

Comment: @stackdisplay I ended up just testing it with an existing one i.e. `[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "0: {0},1: {1}, 2: {2}, "`. I couldn't find any documentation on it. :)

Comment: @stackdisplay Actually someone has detailed it here. `The {0} index is the display name of property, {1} is the MaximumLength, {2} is the MinimumLength. So, your error message will be formate as "The Foo must be at least 6 characters long."` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425320/what-parameters-does-the-stringlength-attribute-errormessage-take

Answer (score 1):

Hi I don't have access to a computer here, but I believe you have to do something along the lines of.

```
public class MyMaxLengthAttribute : MaxLengthAttribute
{
     private static String CustomErrorMessage = "{0} length should not be more than {1}";
     public MyMaxLengthAttribute(int length) : base(length)
     {
         ErrorMessage = "What should I input here"
     }

     public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
     {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
        {
            ErrorMessage = MyErrorMessage;
        }
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, CustomErrorMessage , name);
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is difference in overriding the ErrorMessage in MyMaxLengthAttribute and FormatErrorMessage? Any advantages and disadvatanges? It seems to me that both give the same outcome.

Comment: Hi, to be honest I am not sure. They seem to be doing the same things but they have different definitions i.e. MSDN [ErrorMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.errormessage(v=vs.110).aspx) / MSDN [FormatErrorMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.formaterrormessage(v=vs.110).aspx).